# Spring boot Controller json response has a field name "empty"

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller

I have a GET endpoint in my application supposed to return :

```
{
  "gameId": "41a483c4-6220-424a-a931-d9114a4f6748",
  "pits": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "stones": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "stones": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "stones": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "stones": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "stones": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "stones": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "stones": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "stones": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "stones": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "stones": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "stones": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "stones": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "stones": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "stones": 0
    }
  ],
  "playerTurn": null,
  "currentPitIndex": 0
}
```

but instead it returns:

```
{
    "id": "25f09303-b797-418f-a7e7-db0e5fa8631b",
    "pits": [
        {
            "stones": 6,
            "empty": false
        },
        {
            "stones": 6,
            "empty": false
        },
        {
            "stones": 6,
            "empty": false
        },
        {
            "stones": 6,
            "empty": false
        },
        {
            "stones": 6,
            "empty": false
        },
        {
            "stones": 6,
            "empty": false
        },
        {
            "stones": 0,
            "empty": true
        },
        {
            "stones": 6,
            "empty": false
        },
        {
            "stones": 6,
            "empty": false
        },
        {
            "stones": 6,
            "empty": false
        },
        {
            "stones": 6,
            "empty": false
        },
        {
            "stones": 6,
            "empty": false
        },
        {
            "stones": 6,
            "empty": false
        },
        {
            "stones": 0,
            "empty": true
        }
    ],
    "playerTurn": null,
    "currentPitIndex": null
}
```

I am wondering what is "empty"?! and where is "id"!

would be much appreciated for any suggestion and help.
thank you

Comment: Please provide the method in the `Controller` as well as the object it returns. Rob's answer should point you in the right direction though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your class have a method called `isEmpty()`? Because most JSON marshalling frameworks add JSON properties for any method with 0 arguments that starts with `get`, or returns a boolean and starts with `is`. For the same reason `id` is probably missing - I'm guessing there is no getter for it. The top level `gameId` is probably called `id` because you have a `getId()` method, not a `getGameId()` method.

For most frameworks you can tweak this with annotations. For instance, with Jackon you can use `@JsonIgnore` to indicate a method should not be represented as a JSON property, and `@JsonProperty` can be used to a) add a custom name, or b) allow a field to be included as well. For other frameworks you should check their documentation.

Comment: Hi Rob Spoor, edit:( I made a spelling mistake in my question gameId is actually id). I am not using isEmpty method

Comment: I found isEmpty() metod. checking that the stones value is 0 or not